# How can i integrate Gmail API and send email from rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, integration, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

i want send email from my rails application by integrating the Gmail API(Oauth Authentication).

When i check the doucumentation, there is a code available for google drive integration only(https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client).

But no where i found the information on sendig email from Gmail by using this('google-api-client') ruby gem, or any rails gem,can some one help me with integratation part & send email from the rails Application using Gmail API.

From my google account, i created the google App,and enabled gmail Api to that google App. and downloaded the client id, client secrets file.

```
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.34'
```

Comment: I recomend starting here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby  This will show you how to get the Oauth part working and give you a taste of working with the Library.

Comment: Then check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40263412/1841839

Comment: Does the ruby client support rails?